# Presenting Sheet modally in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to present a modal sheet upon selecting the menu item in the navigation bar. But, the sheet is not displayed. Upon debugging I noticed that the state variable `showSheet` is not getting updated and I am sort of lost as to why it is not updating.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

There is another post ([@State not updating in SwiftUI 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666415/state-not-updating-in-swiftui-2)) that has a similar issue. Is this a bug in SwiftUI?

Below is a full sample

I have a `fileprivate enum` that defines two cases for the views - `add` and `edit`

```
fileprivate enum SheetView {
    case add, edit
}
```

Below is the ContentView. The ContentView declares two `@State` variables that are set based on the menu item selected
The menu items (`var actionItems`) are on the `NavigationView` and has menu with 2 buttons - Add and Edit. Each button has an action set to toggle the `showSheetView` and the `showSheet` variables. The content is presented based on which item is selected. Content is built using `@ViewBuilder`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheetView = false
    @State private var showSheet: SheetView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            NavigationView {
                Text("Main Page")
                    .padding()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: actionItems)
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheetView) {
            content
        }
    }
    
    var actionItems: some View {
        Menu {
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = .add
                showSheetView.toggle()
            }) {
                Label("Add Asset", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = .edit
                showSheetView.toggle()
            }) {
                Label("Edit Asset", systemImage: "minus")
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "dot.circle.and.cursorarrow").resizable()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var content: some View {
        if let currentView = showSheet {
            switch currentView {
            case .add:
                AddAsset(showSheetView: $showSheetView)
            case .edit:
                EditAsset(showSheetView: $showSheetView)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Below are the two Views - `AddAsset` and `EditAsset`

```
struct AddAsset: View {
    @Binding var showSheetView: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Add Asset")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    print("Dismissing sheet view...")
                    self.showSheetView = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
        }
    }
}

struct EditAsset: View {
    @Binding var showSheetView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Edit Asset")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    print("Dismissing sheet view...")
                    self.showSheetView = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `sheet(item:` variant.

Here is fixed code (there are many changes so all components included). Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
enum SheetView: Identifiable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case add, edit
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet: SheetView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            NavigationView {
                Text("Main Page")
                    .padding()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: actionItems)
            }
        }.sheet(item: $showSheet) { mode in
            content(for: mode)
        }
    }
    
    var actionItems: some View {
        Menu {
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = .add
            }) {
                Label("Add Asset", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = .edit
            }) {
                Label("Edit Asset", systemImage: "minus")
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "dot.circle.and.cursorarrow").resizable()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func content(for mode: SheetView) -> some View {
        switch mode {
        case .add:
            AddAsset(showSheet: $showSheet)
        case .edit:
            EditAsset(showSheet: $showSheet)
        }
    }
    
}

struct AddAsset: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: SheetView?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Add Asset")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Add"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    print("Dismissing sheet view...")
                    self.showSheet = nil
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
        }
    }
}

struct EditAsset: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: SheetView?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Edit Asset")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    print("Dismissing sheet view...")
                    self.showSheet = nil
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
                })
        }
    }
}
```