# sheet not showing when presented from button in Menu - SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui, menu

Still some what new to SwiftUI. Now I'm trying to present a sheet from a button in a Menu. I can reproduce the issue with the sample code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
  
  var body: some View {
    Button("Press to dismiss") {
      presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    .font(.title)
    .padding()
    .background(Color.black)
  }
}

struct TestButtonInMenu: View {
  @State private var showingSheet = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button("Show Sheet") {
      showingSheet.toggle()
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
      SheetView()
    }
  }
}

enum SampleEnum: String, CaseIterable {
  case one, two, three, four
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section {
        VStack  {
          ForEach(SampleEnum.allCases, id:\.self) { id in
            Menu("\(Text(id.rawValue))") {
              TestButtonInMenu()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried different sheet initializers but they don't make a difference.

What am I missing? Is this possible in SwiftUI?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65137153/12299030?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems with the code. First of all, in your `ContentView` you have the `Menu` inside of the `ForEach`. By doing it that way, you have created four menus with one button each, instead of one menu with four buttons. The point of `Menu` is to hide the buttons until they are needed.

The second issue is that you are trying to show one sheet off the button that is buried in another view in the menu. The sheet really should be declared in the parent, not a child, and I think you have confused the OS. That being said, I think eventually you intend to call four different sheets from the different buttons, and the answer Asperi pointed you to will help as you will be calling different sheets from the one `.sheet`. I corrected the code and just brought the button into the main UI and out of its own struct.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Press to dismiss") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}

enum SampleEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three, four
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                VStack  {
                    Menu("Show Sheet") {
                        ForEach(SampleEnum.allCases, id:\.self) { id in
                            Button(id.rawValue) {
                                showingSheet.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your re-write works but it doesn't really reproduce my requirements. I have a list of items (as in SampleEnum). Each one allows a Menu to come up with  four options (as in in the old ContextMenu from UIKit table and collection views which showed with a long press). That's why it's inside the ForEach. Three options work find but the fourth option needs to show a sheet. My problem is that the sheet doesn't show.

Comment: I don't think Asperi's suggestion helps either but I have to look at it in more detail.