# Calling a sheet from a menu item

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app that has to display a small dialog with some information when the user presses the menu item "Info".

I've tried calling doing this with a `.sheet` but can't get it to display the sheet. Code:

```
@main
struct The_ThingApp: App {
    private let dataModel = DataModel()
    @State var showsAlert = false
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false

    var body: some Scene {
       WindowGroup {
          ContentView()
          .environmentObject(self.dataModel)
       }
       .commands {
            CommandMenu("Info") {
                Button("Get Info") { 
                    print("getting info")
                    isShowingSheet.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Some stuff to be shown")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(50)
                        Button("Dismiss",
                               action: { isShowingSheet.toggle() })
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

How would I display a sheet from a menu item?

However, if a sheet is not the way to do it (I think given the simplicity of what I need to show, it would be it), how would you suggest I do it? I tried creating a new view, like I did with the preferences window, but I can't call it either from the menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65137153/12299030?

Comment: Thanks @Asperi but I have no problem calling a sheet from within my views, it's from the main app entry point, where the menus for a macOS app (no iOS) are declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a little late to the party, but will hopefully provide some guidance that will work well with multi-window apps. After watching, [SwiftUI on the Mac: Build the fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10062/) from WWDC20 and reviewing the [Apple Developer Docs for focusedSceneValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focusedscenevalue(_:_:)-57boz), the best way to show a sheet while respecting multiple windows is through the use of `focusedSceneValue`.

If you have a lot of stuff that's dependent upon the selected/focused `Scene`, you could use `@FocusedObject` instead, similar to using `@EnvironmentObject`.

Set up a key to show up in the list of options when using `@FocusedValue` in the button:

```
struct ShowSheetKey: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Binding<Bool>
}

extension FocusedValues {
    var showSheet: Binding<Bool>? {
        get { self[ShowSheetKey.self] }
        set { self[ShowSheetKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

In your `ContentView` create state to control your sheet's presentation and link it using the `.focusedSceneValue` modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
        // This will make an instance of the showSheet binding outside of the view, to any view that peels it out via @FocusedValue (similar to using @Environment)
        .focusedSceneValue(\.showSheet, $showSheet)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("I'm in a sheet!")
        }
    }
}
```

Create a button that can be used to create the menu command.

```
struct ShowSheetButton: View {
    @FocusedValue(\.showSheet) private var showSheet
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showSheet?.wrappedValue = true
        } label: {
            Label("Show Sheet", systemImage: "eye")
        }
        .disabled(showSheet == nil)
    }
}
```

Finally, update your `commands` modifier in the `Scene` of your `App`.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
                ShowSheetButton()
                    .keyboardShortcut("n", modifiers: [.command, .shift])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. It's a clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

put the sheet directly on `ContentView`:

```
@main
struct The_ThingApp: App {
    
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                // here VV
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Some stuff to be shown")
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(50)
                        Button("Dismiss",
                               action: { isShowingSheet.toggle() })
                    }
                }
        }
        
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Info") {
                Button("Get Info") {
                    print("getting info")
                    isShowingSheet.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn’t work well when working with multiple windows and scenes. Each scene will share that State and display the sheet.